# Extract particular part of string matching regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

I have a string

> /example/look-into-it/date-2014-08-23-to-2014-08-30

and I need a regexp so that I can get following 4 items from this string:

> part1: example part2: look-into-it date_from: 2014-08-23 date_to:
>   2014-08-30

Any Help on regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "/example/look-into-it/date-2014-08-23-to-2014-08-30"

data = s.match(/\/(?<part1>.*)\/(?<part2>.*)\/date\-(?<date_from>.*)\-to\-(?<date_to>.*)/)
=> #<MatchData
"/example/look-into-it/date-2014-08-23-to-2014-08-30"
part1:"example"
part2:"look-into-it"
date_from:"2014-08-23"
date_to:"2014-08-30">
md[:part1]
=> "example"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "/example/look-into-it/date-2014-08-23-to-2014-08-30"
md = s.match(/\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/date\-(.*)\-to\-(.*)/)
p md[1..4]
```

result:

```
["example", "look-into-it", "2014-08-23", "2014-08-30"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit longer but this is a case where regexp might just make things harder to read:

```
s = "/example/look-into-it/date-2014-08-23-to-2014-08-30"
s.slice!(0) # Remove first '/'

words, dates = s.split('/date-')
part1, part2 = words.split('/')
date_from, date_to = dates.split('-to-')
```